# How do I update a single instance in a Store?

Tags: html, model, sencha-touch-2, store

I have a Store used to back a List. When I tap on a list item, I show a "details" panel. One of the buttons on the details panel initiates a POST request to initiate a server-side operation. This changes the status on the server side from "idle" to "in-progress". To update the UI on the details panel, I then load the latest data for this instance by calling load() on the Model class, e.g.

```
MyApp.model.Server.load(serverId, 
    success: function(record, operation) {
        // code that updates the current view
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to update the instance in the underlying Store. So when I go back to the list, there is stale data for the server I tapped on (still says "idle").

Is there a way I can take the updated Server instance and update just that record in the Store? I don't want to have to reload my entire Store just to update the UI for one record.

I tried updating the instance in the Store, to no avail:

```
Ext.getStore('Server').getById(serverId).data = record.data;
```

Am I missing something here? Or do I really have to reload the whole Store just to get the updated status for one record?

Answer (score 1):

No, you dont need reload all store and inst good update a record data manualy.

Correct:

`var record = Ext.getStore('Server').first();`

`record.set(form.getData());`

`record.save();`

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for exactly - this will trigger a save operation to the server. 

But I'm not saving any local changes from a form, I want to update my local copy of the object in the store with a fresh copy of the remote object.

Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: You can update the record in memory without reload the store, that way:
`var recordStr = store.first()`

`recordStr.set(record.getData())`

This code will update the record. You need use the `set()` method